# SVM hard and soft margins in matlab,

Tags: classification, svm, matlab, hyperparameter

I am comparing the performances of several SVM models in matlab using the `fitcsvm` function,
and I want to double check that I am using the correct syntax
for hard soft amragins and kernel:
the syntax of hard margin should be as follows, in which the hyperparameter of hard margin cost (boxConstraint) should be infinite

```
%Hard Margin
SVMModel = fitcsvm(x_train,y_train,'BoxConstraint',Inf);
```

while the soft margin, the boxConstraint (which is the only hyperparameter needed for soft margin)should be tuned and given a suitable value, for example

```
 %soft Margin
    SVMModel = fitcsvm(x_train,y_train,'BoxConstraint', 7);
```

or leave it as default (which has the boxconstraint as 1)

```
SVMModel = fitcsvm(x_train,y_train);
```

and for the kernel model, say RBF, both boxconstrains and KernelScale (gamma) should be tuned and used

```
    SVMModel = fitcsvm(x_train,y_train, KernelFunction, 'RBF',...
'BoxConstraint', 7,'KernelScale', '0.3');
```

assuming the all hyperparameters are tuned, is the previous syntax considered correct to have hard, soft and kernel models in Matlab?

Also, in case of cross-validation of the model, how to get the best hyperparameters while the SVM model is cross-validated? or selecting the hyperparamters step should be before cross-validating the model?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55544728/5341713